# PC HDMI Output to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian

I’ve been googling for a while and am coming up dry so I thought it was worth asking here. I’m interested in building a distributed display presentation system where the presenter uses a PC and the secondary monitor replaces across multiple raspberry pi’s.

In other words, I’d like to use a raspberry pi as a second monitor for my PC, but have multiple raspberry pi’s (all mirror of each other)

The primary use would be PowerPoint or a web browser on the PC. Is this even possible? I’m also open to arduino or netduino

Comment: your title is misleading, since a raspberry pi's hdmi is also an output, you can't connect an output to an output - it's against the will of god :p

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. || Your question is somehow confusing. So, as I understood, you need a [KVM Switch](https://www.amazon.com/KVM-Switches/b?ie=UTF8&node=13983771).

Comment: I’m sorry it’s confusing. To be clear I’m not looking to use the HDMI output of the Pi as an input. I’m looking to see if anyone knows of tech to stream to a Pi. Maybe a module that adds HDMI input to it. Maybe a USB device. Maybe a web technology. I’m not sure what’s out there. It doesn’t seem like very much.

Comment: Would a [VNC Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) do what you want?